# "Hackable" router+modem combo

Tags: wifi, router

I am looking for a router+modem+wifi combo. I want this modem to be "hackable". What that means is:

It should run some kind of linux, allowing to set custom cron jobs, adding features to the web UI and setting custom local domain. I don't need it to be open source, just "hackable" with some reasonable effort.

The main requirement is this that it's possible to SSH into it and that I can reset it to factory settings if I screw up something.

Comment: I can't recommend a specific router, but anything on [this list](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) or [this list](https://openwrt.org/supported_devices) is probably going to provide everything you're asking for.  Flashing one of those custom firmwares may be necessary to unlock SSH or modify the UI on most routers though.

Comment: I'm afraid @Romen is right - aside from running WRT on a customer device, your only other choice is a PC (a NUC maybe?). Typically devices with that level of software are used in situations when you _want_ the router separated from the WiFi AP or the modem. Assuming they run GNU/Linux not something like RouterOS (which is a custom Linux OS, in a similar sense to Android).